# Custom qsort comparator function with multiple fields within struct in C

Tags: c, struct, qsort

I'm trying to sort a struct in a particuar way. As you can see in the following struct, fields are sorted by `product` name.

```
       a   -   $13.00
 a.0|100   -   $3.00
 a.1|100   -   $6.00
 a.2|100   -   $4.00
       b   -   $25.00
 b.0|100   -   $2.00
 b.1|100   -   $10.00
 b.2|100   -   $13.00
```

I'm wondering how could I preserve the sort by `product` name, but at the same time, "sub-sort" each product by `price`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 

struct st_ex { 
    char product[16];
    float price;
};

int struct_cmp_by_product(const void *a, const void *b) { 
    struct st_ex *ia = (struct st_ex *)a;
    struct st_ex *ib = (struct st_ex *)b;
    return strcmp(ia->product, ib->product);
} 

int main() { 
    struct st_ex structs[] = {
        {"b", 25}, 
        {"b.0|100", 2}, 
        {"b.1|100", 10},
        {"b.2|100", 13},
        {"a", 13},
        {"a.0|100", 3},
        {"a.1|100", 6},
        {"a.2|100", 4},
    };  
    size_t structs_len = sizeof(structs) / sizeof(struct st_ex);
    qsort(structs, structs_len, sizeof(struct st_ex), struct_cmp_by_product);    
    size_t i;
    for(i=0; i<structs_len; i++) 
        printf("%8s   -   $%.2f\n", structs[i].product, structs[i].price);
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**: Sorting by price but grouping by name. e.g., `b:25` > `a:13`

```
       b   -   $25.00
 b.2|100   -   $13.00
 b.1|100   -   $10.00
 b.0|100   -   $2.00
       a   -   $13.00
 a.1|100   -   $6.00
 a.2|100   -   $4.00
 a.0|100   -   $3.00
```

Comment: Thank you guys, makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Homework?  Does anyone write this kind of stuff in C anymore?

Think about what your goal is: if the product name is different, then it makes no difference what the price is, so you return the name comparison result.

It's only if the product name is the same that the price matters.

So *two* problems need fixing. A more application-aware replacement for `strcmp(3)` is needed, one that knows that `b`, `b.0|100`, and `b.0|200` should compare equally as a product "names". And, of course, in the equality case, it's necessary to add a comparison of the prices. The code below replaces your comparison function and has been tested. By the way, you don't need to cast conversions to and from `void *` if you are working in plain C.

```
int baseproductname(const char *a, const char *b) {
    for(;;) {
        int c = *a;
        int d = *b;
        if (c == '.')
            c = 0;
        if (d == '.')
            d = 0;
        if(c != d || !c || !d)
            return c - d;
        ++a;
        ++b;
    }
}

int productorder(const struct st_ex *a, const struct st_ex *b) {
    int n = baseproductname(a->product, b->product);
    printf("%s <=> %s is %d\n", a->product, b->product, n);
    if (n)
        return n;
    if (a->price > b->price)
        return -1;
    return a->price < b->price;
}

int struct_cmp_by_product(const void *a, const void *b) {
  return productorder(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to modify your `struct_cmp_by_product`. Instead of doing a `strcmp`, compare for the product names (depending on how long your product name is you may want to use `strcmp` on a substring of the `product` member).

I would however prefer to encode this distinction within the `st_ex` type by keeping two members which when combined gives the actual product name.

```
 struct st_ex {
      char product[ 4 ]; // product group
      char subgroup[ 12 ]; // sub group
      float price;
 }

 int struct_cmp_by_product(const void *a, const void *b) { 
    struct st_ex  const *ia = a; // do not cast away const-ness!
    struct st_ex const *ib = b;
    int x = strcmp(ia->product, ib->product);
    if (!x) {
        return ia->price > ib->price;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `x` be true at all times?

Comment: I assumed `product` field contains `a`, `b` etc. and the `subgroup` field contains `.0|100` part. So, I don't see why `x` would be true always. But when it is true, we sort by price (and not name). Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The key is to be able to identify produce names. This of course depends on the format of product names. If what you have written here is precise, then it means the word that comes before `.` if any. Let's construct the compare function piece by piece:

```
int struct_cmp_by_product(const void *a, const void *b) { 
    struct st_ex *ia = (struct st_ex *)a;
    struct st_ex *ib = (struct st_ex *)b;
```

First, we'd have to find where the `.` happens:

```
    size_t len_a, len_b;
    char *a_dot, *b_dot;
    a_dot = strchr(ia->product, '.');
    b_dor = strchr(ib->product, '.');
    if (a_dot)
        len_a = a_dot - ia->product;
    else
        len_a = strlen(ia->product);
    if (b_dot)
        len_b = b_dot - ib->product;
    else
        len_b = strlen(ib->product);
```

We then have to check if the two product names are equal:

```
    int res; /* define above */
    if (len_a == len_b && strncmp(ia->product, ib->product, len_a) == 0)
    {
        /* then check for price */
    }
    else
        return strcmp(ia->product, ib->product);
```

and the part to compare the prices is simply given as:

```
        if (ia->price < ib->price)
            return -1;
        if (ia->price > ib->price)
            return 1;
        return 0;
```

And finally to close the function:

```
}
```

Note: I may be missing error checking or have typos, make sure you understand the code before using it. Don't just copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

```
int struct_cmp_by_product(const void *a, const void *b) {
    struct st_ex *ia = (struct st_ex *)a;
    struct st_ex *ib = (struct st_ex *)b;
    int rc;
    size_t len_a, len_b, len;

    len_a = strcspn(ia->product, ".");
    len_b = strcspn(ib->product, ".");
    len = (len_a > len_b) ? len_a : len_b; /* assuming ascii */
    rc = strncmp(ia->product, ib->product, len);
    if (rc) return rc;

    if (ia->price > ab-price) rc = 1;
    else if (ia->price < ab-price) rc = -1;
    return rc;
}
```

UPDATE: strcmp() -->> strncmp + calculate sizes

Comment: Wouldn't `strcmp` return true all the time? I can't see when it would compare prices.

Comment: strcmp() returns zero, or less than zero, or more than zero. The `if (rc)` condition tests for the not-equal-zero condition, so the compare-price will only take place if the product names are equal.

Comment: But this doesn't work. The product names are actually different in the strcmp sense ... you need to sort on only part of the product "name".

Comment: If the product names are different, the function will return early, **before** the compare on prices.

Comment: That's exactly the problem, he obviously intends `a` and `a.0` to be considered the same product, and in that case sort by the price. If you would just *test* your solution you would see the problem. (His code does compile and run as presented, but using plain strcmp(3) does an overly strict name comparison. There are actually *two* problems in the code.)

Comment: That's where I was confused. Thanks!

Comment: I that case he needs to alter his data modelling. Or use an extreme customised compare function, which looks for the '.' first,and compares using strncmp(), with the third argument composed of the min (position of '.'found in a or b).

Comment: Anyway, I updated my answer, using a substring-hack. (I read too fast, obviously)